# Terminology: Does a judge have a career in "litigation"?

Tags: criminal-law, legal-terms

I'm working on a song parody, satirizing a notably litigious group of people, and have run up against a little issue of "accuracy of terminology" and "phrasing that reflects my intentions" vs. scansion.  Ideally, I'd like my song's narrator to possibly be a judge or a lawyer, left ambiguous: someone whose profession is in criminal law, though if I have to choose just one, it would be the voice of a judge.  Could "Litigation's my career" apply to a judge, rather than only to a lawyer?  "Adjudication's my career" would fit only a judge.  Are there other "[X] is my career" terms which would cover both cases while still being short, and relatively common in the English language such that a listener who's not a legal expert would have no trouble understanding it in song lyrics?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because that is not a question about law. This belongs to a language specific stack, such as [English.SE]